# drawing on canvas after jquery ready

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I've just started developing some small games using the HTML5 canvas tag and javascript. But as I started I found that when I call the jquery ready handler like this:

```
<script>$(function(){ game.init(); })</script>
```

And then I try to draw an image (that pre-exists in my markup) like this:

```
var spaceshipImg = $('#imgSpaceship')[0];
game.context.drawImage(spaceshipImg, 0, 350);
```

It wont work, as if the img hasn't loaded yet. However if I call this same method placing an 'onload' in my body tag, then it does work. According to jQuery documentation, all images should be loaded at this point, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has two different methods for the purposes of waiting for everything to be loaded: a `ready` and a `load` method. The `ready` method is used when using the `$(function() {})` syntax. This method does not wait for all images to be loaded though (see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)). For that you want to use the `load` method. Your code would then become:

```
<script>
  $(window).load(function () {
    game.init();
  });
</script>
```

Now the `init` method is only called when all resources (including images) have been loaded.